# Allow figure to continue next page if it doesn't fit

Tags: floats, sidewaysfigure

I am using the following command to combine figure and want to let them continue next page if they don't fit in the page.

```latex
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratebcbd} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratebmres} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratecagdp}\\

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grrateexportsclcu} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grrateimportsclcu} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratecausd} \\

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratedomcredit} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grrateres} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratergdp} \\

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratenetfdi} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratereerwb} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grrateresdebt} \\

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratetot1} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grratedebtgdp} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{grrintr} \\


\end{tabular}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises}
 \label{fig: cc}
\end{figure}
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: How is this related to the seidawysfigure environment from the rotating package? Please also note that a figure environment itself can not break across pages. To solve your problem, you might want to take a look at continuedfloat

Answer (score 2):

You can use longtable, particularly to replace a tabular.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
\usepackage{duckuments}% for variety

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{20\baselineskip}

\renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
\begin{longtable}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises \label{fig: cc}}
\endhead
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\\
%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} &
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works quite well but I still can't figure something out. First, the caption of figure goes at the end of figure and I don't know how to put them at the top.  Second, the caption should be in every page of figure not only in the last with a text to continue next page. How can I do that?

Comment: See the longtable manual for a complete list.  \endhead will put the caption at the top of every page.

Comment: Even if I include \endhead in this figure the caption still stays at the bottom. I thing something is stopping it to go at the top. Maybe I should exclude something.

Comment: See edited version.