# Placement of multipage figure

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, springernature

I am trying to insert 4 page figure with 11 subfigures. I am using springer-nature template on Overleaf. I have 2 tables just below the multipage figure.

When I execute the code the multipage figure goes 2 pages back before the table in the same subsection and the 4th page of the figure goes after the table.

If I use the placement specifier such `[t]` the figure goes all the ways to the end, even after the references.

Here is the relevant part of the code for the figure. I copied this code from LyX code preview pane to save time and avoid searching stackexchange for the syntax.

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Model 2]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/deepxde2d/solutions}

}

\subfloat[Model 3]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_3/solutions}

}

\subfloat[Model 4]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_4/solutions}

}
\caption{Solution of 2D steady-state heat conduction problem\label{fig:Solution-of-2D}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat

\subfloat[Model 5]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_5/solutions}

}

\subfloat[Model 6]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_6/solutions}

}

\subfloat[Model 7]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_7/solutions}

}
\caption{Solution of 2D steady-state heat conduction problem\label{fig:Solution-of-2D-1}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\subfloat[Model 8]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_8/solutions}

}

\subfloat[Model 9]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_9/solutions}

}

\subfloat[Model 10]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_10/solutions}

}
\caption{Solution of 2D steady-state heat conduction problem\label{fig:Solution-of-2D-2}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\subfloat[Model 11]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./Images/model_11/solutions}

}

\caption{Solution of 2D steady-state heat conduction problem\label{fig:Solution-of-2D-3}}

\end{figure}
```

Page screenshot:
[image]

See that the table comes in between the figure·

Comment: Have you tried [!ht] option?

Comment: I just tried it. It worked. But why? You can write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: There are some rules for latex to place floats. `!` is actually make the float placement ignore these rules. If you don't use any placement option, latex will choose the appropriate place for you.  You could take a look this post. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures

Comment: BTW, You MWE was not working. You don't have `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in it. However, even you did put them in it, your document class was not a standard one either. So someone else can not just grab it and play it to see how it work. Improve you MWE you will get more attention to your question.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645897/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages-automatically